# PHP help - array and img

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having problems with a plugin in wordpress. I want to customize it but I don't know PHP at all and have no idea what or where I should modify so that I can replace those "»" and «" with images.

This is the code I believe it's responsible for this:

```
// Set defaults
if ($ta_multipage == '' OR $_POST["ta_multipage_Reset"]) {
    $ta_multipage = array (
        'mp1_before'            => '',
        'mp1_after'             => '',
        'mp1_title_number'      => 2,
        'mp1_quick_type'        => 1,
        'mp1_nav_type'          => 2,
        'mp1_nav_number'        => 'True',
        'mp1_previouspagelink'  => '&laquo;',
        'mp1_nextpagelink'      => '&raquo;',
        'mp1_firstpagetext'     => 'On First Page',
        'mp1_lastpagetext'      => 'On Last Page',
        'mp1_display_all'       => 'True',
        'mp1_display_all_text'  => 'View All',          
        'mp1_div_align'         => 'center',
        'mp1_insert_top'        => 'False',
        'mp1_insert_bottom'     => 'False',
        'mp1_insert_pages'      => 'False',
        'mp2_before'            => 'Page :',
        'mp2_after'             => '',
        'mp2_title_number'      => 2,
        'mp2_quick_type'        => 2,
        'mp2_nav_type'          => 0,
        'mp2_nav_number'        => 'True',
        'mp2_previouspagelink'  => '&laquo;',
        'mp2_nextpagelink'      => '&raquo;',
        'mp2_firstpagetext'     => 'On First Page',
        'mp2_lastpagetext'      => 'On Last Page',
        'mp2_display_all'       => 'True',
        'mp2_display_all_text'  => 'ALL',
        'mp2_div_align'         => 'center',
        'mp2_insert_top'        => 'False',
        'mp2_insert_bottom'     => 'False',
        'mp2_insert_pages'      => 'False',
        'seperator'             => '2',
        'seperator_code'        => "--~~~~~~~~~~~~--"
    );
    update_option("ta_multipage", $ta_multipage);
    update_option("ta_multipage_priority", 99);
}

// removes slahes to display code correctly in textarea
```

Comment: replace with valid html image tag, should work.

Comment: ...the code responsible for **what**?  How are we supposed to have any clue as to what you're asking?

Comment: I think those `&raquo;` and `&laquo;` are exactly the angle quotes characters you're looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not played with Wordpress for quite a while, but I think the lines you'll need to edit are these. These should, when rendered in the HTML, generate the relevant images:

```
'mp1_previouspagelink'  => '<img src="http://path.to/previousPageImage.png" />',
'mp1_nextpagelink'      => '<img src="http://path.to/nextPageImage.png" />',
// ...other stuff...
'mp2_previouspagelink'  => '<img src="http://path.to/previousPageImage.png" />',
'mp2_nextpagelink'      => '<img src="http://path.to/nextPageImage.png" />',
```

Comment: There are more then these two lines that contains `&laquo;` and `&raquo;`.

Comment: @corubba...that'll teach me not to look properly! **Edited** =D

Comment: Thanks! And sorry if I wasn't explicit enough but I'm really a noob when it comes to PHP...